# How can I share the pretty version of my developer story?

Tags: feature-request, stack-overflow-jobs

I'm hosting my CV on Stack Overflow and I link to it from my LinkedIn. I got a reaction from a recruiter saying that the link doesn't work, so I did some digging to find out what went wrong.

My findings are that the two links you can see under `https://stackoverflow.com/users/storypreferences/{user_id}#privacy`; `https://stackoverflow.com/story/{username}` and `https://stackoverflow.com/cv/{username}` are publicly available for everyone (if you make them so). But these present the rather ugly plain text version of the cv. I used the link `https://stackoverflow.com/users/story/pdf/{user_id}?View=Pdf`, which I found by going to my developer story and copying the link under the 'download pdf' button, for my LinkedIn profile page. It automatically downloads the pdf with the much prettier design, with blue highlights and nice margins. I had tested the link and it worked perfectly, but after my investigation I found out the link does not work if the person following it doesn't have a Stack Overflow account.

It's not a matter of privacy settings, everyone can still access this link, but they *need* an account to do so. While the other links don't require being logged in to access them. It is the same data, just presented in a much better format.

Is it possible to link to this version of the cv pdf, without the need for the link follower to have an Stack Overflow account? If so, how? If not, should it be possible?

Edit: Someone I forgot the name of and @poke mentioned that generating a PDF is quite costly, I would understand if therefore the link only works for members of the community. If this is the reason, is caching the document a possibility? Could it be generated client side for non-members?

Comment: My guess: PDF generation is somewhat expensive, so you should probably download it and host it somewhere else. Btw., I do not understand why you say that the story or CV links are “ugly plain text versions”. Those look much better than the generated PDF for me. (And btw. 2, if I open the `View=Pdf` link for your CV, *then* I get an ugly/broken plain text view).

Comment: @poke I like this method because it incorporates my SO profile. As for the style, I prefer the one where the document is divided into sections by blue lines and every section has a blue title to the left of it. It's much clearer what everything is, it makes scanning the document a matter of seconds, which is what I look for in cvs and I assume most people do. The plain text one is not clear at all, it's all the same font and font size, it doesn't have titles and the spacing is awful. It's impossible to find the info you seek at a glance if you don't know the layout beforehand.

Comment: Sorry, but I really have no idea which versions you actually refer to. Can you maybe post some screenshots? [This link](https://stackoverflow.com/users/story/1051292?view=Pdf) (open in a private tab) looks pretty bad to me, while [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/users/story/1051292?view=Cv) looks okay. But the `https://stackoverflow.com/cv/your-public-name` should look much better. And there’s definitely more formatting than “plain text” on that.

Comment: @poke By cv I mean the pdf, so if you go to either of those two pages and press the print button, I see I haven't been very clear about that in the question, sorry. The version I mean can be compared [here](https://imgur.com/a/3rmIcNP)

Comment: Note that nobody except yourself can generate your PDF. I don’t have a “download PDF” button for your CV.

Answer (score 4):

The PDF version of your developer story an only be created by the owner of it. So only I can generate mine and only you can generate yours.

If you want to link to the PDF, you will have to download the file and upload it to a hosting provider. One free option for that is to use [GitHub Pages](https://help.github.com/articles/what-is-github-pages/). You can create a repository there to host the PDF and maybe even a simple static website too.